# Tkinter widget positioning inside frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid, widget

I am trying to position my buttons using the grid manager, by altering the column and row arguments of the `.grid()` function. However, whenever I input values > 1, there seems to be no change in position of my widgets. Why is this?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.rowconfigure(0,weight=1) 
window.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

f1 = tk.Frame(window,bg="black")
f1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

btn1 = tk.Button(f1,text="button")
btn1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
lbl = tk.Label(f1,text="label")
lbl.grid(row=3,column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If there is no widget in a row or column, the size of the row or column will be zero.

Comment: unless You define row or column with `grid_rowconfigure()`/`grid_columnconfigure()`

Comment: So how would I go about placing a single widget in, let's say, the centre, using a specific column number without wanting to have anything on either side if every column must be filled in?

Comment: If you just want to put a *single* widget in the center of the window, it is easier to use `place()` instead of `grid()`: `widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="c")`.